# Redirecting and converting MySQL queries to Postgres on the server side

Tags: mysql, postgresql, replication, mirroring

The first thing I would like to say is that I'm not going to build a production on such an architecture. I am interested purely for the sake of experiments in home experiments and performance in the amount of 1-2 users.

What I need:

- One data storage location from SQL database
- The ability to connect using different drivers and different SQL dialects
- Isolation of data from the method, libraries and syntax of obtaining them

What I don't need:

- Replication between different databases, creating duplicate data and tables

---

For example:
I have two apps. The first uses MySQL. The second uses Postgres. It is impossible to rewrite them on one database (for one reason or another).
I want them to be able to connect each with their own driver and syntax, to the same data. At the same time, the data itself is not replicated, it is stored in a single instance.

Please tell me how you can achieve a similar logic? What tools or settings can be used to achieve this? Which way should I move?

Comment: With the lack of specific details on the goal or reasoning on why you don't want to replicate data, there is no possible answer to your question. In general, if you don't want to move the data, but you want the app to interact with more than one database, then the application code will need to change, and can use an ORM that works with multiple database systems.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know how to compose this question in even more detail. I need cross compatibility on the server side. The reason is simple. I need one database that would be compatible with any dialect. In this case, it is compatible with both MySQL and Postgres at the same time. Isolate the implementation from storage. The disadvantage of replication is obvious - a multiple increase in data volume. I need something like proxying or, I do not know, a plugin to convert the dialect in the database itself.

Comment: "*To be honest, I do not know how to compose this question in even more detail.*" - Well for one, you say each app uses a separate database system but then further on you say the data is stored in a single instance. So it's a little confusing what your current setup even is. Are there currently two separate databases, one in MySQL and one in PostgreSQL?...are they structured **exactly** the same way?...is the data being maintained such that it's exactly the same in both databases? If not, why is the data in both databases needed to be accessed by both apps? Is the app code not accessible?...

Comment: ...is this because it's a 3rd party app? These details & more descriptive information on the why of your end goal would clarify such a uniquely different request you have. Aside from ORMs and changing app code, purely at the database layer usually you can install & utilize the drivers of other database systems to then access their data directly from that database instance. The features and methodologies of doing this differ by name between database systems mostly, so I'm not sure what it would be called for MySQL or PostgreSQL, but Microsoft SQL Server calls them Linked Servers, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know little about MySQL but you can have a MySQL “real” database, and then use PostgreSQL’s *foreign data wrappers* to use your MySQL database through PostgreSQL. Note that you won’t be able to user DDL commands to modify the structure of the MySQL database through PostgreSQL, and you may have some restrictions to the DML commands you may run.